# Insert data-bind values inside textarea as a default canned message using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to figure out how I can insert data-bind values inside a textarea as a canned message. Here is an example

```
<textarea ng-init='message="Buy {{ get_value }} and get {{ free_value }} free for every purchase"' class="text-input referral-message" ng-model="message" rows="5">
</textarea>
```

I tried this kind of solution, but the output shows the data-bind and not the value itself

---

```
$timeout(function() {

    ReferralService.settings().$promise.then(function(settings) {
        $scope.purchase_count = settings.credits;
    });

    $scope.buildMessage = function(val){
      return "Buy " + val + " and get 1 free for every purchase"
    }
}, 1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to avoid such approach of `ng-init`

If you want to use `ng-init`, I would try something like:

```
<textarea ng-init="message=buildMessage(get_value,free_value)" 
          ng-model="message" rows="5">
</textarea>
```

Where `buildMessage` is:

```
$scope.buildMessage = function(val,free){
  return "Buy " + val + " and get " + free + " free for every purchase"
}
```

I think this is a clean way and doesn't enter noise to your HTML.

Try to stay with simple HTML as possible.

---

**[EDIT]**

```
$timeout(function() {

  ReferralService.settings().$promise.then(function(settings) {
    $scope.purchase_count = settings.credits;
  });
});

$scope.buildMessage = function(val){
  return "Buy " + val + " and get 1 free for every purchase"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, what if the `$scope` is inside `$timeout`? The canned message doesn't seem to render/appear if it was like that

Comment: @clestcruz plse take this demo and add `$timeout` regards to your needs: http://plnkr.co/edit/yxRtnFE9776Euellzw1l?p=preview

Comment: kinda hard to explain since I'm still new angular. Decided to update my question instead even though I already accepted your answer. Added some new code